# MySQL: Solve my MySQL Cursor Error:1064

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-administration

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `ACTUALIZAR_LOTE_DETALLE`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `ACTUALIZAR_LOTE_DETALLE` AFTER INSERT ON `detalle_envio`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
DECLARE ID_INVENTARIO_IN INT;
DECLARE ID_LOTE_DETALLE_MIN INT;
DECLARE CANTIDAD_A_COMPARAR INT;
DECLARE CANTIDAD_A_RESTAR INT;
SET CANTIDAD_A_RESTAR = new.cantidad_enviado;
SET ID_INVENTARIO_IN = (Select id_inventario from detalle_requisicion WHERE id_detalle_requisicion = new.id_detalle_requisicion); 
DECLARE cur_id CURSOR FOR SELECT id_lote_detalle from lote_detalle WHERE id_inventario = ID_INVENTARIO_IN AND cantidad > 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = 1;
OPEN cur_id;    
read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur_id INTO LOTE_DETALLE_IDS;
SET CANTIDAD_A_COMPARAR = select cantidad from lote_detalle where id_lote_detalle = LOTE_DETALLE_IDS;
IF CANTIDAD_A_RESTAR > CANTIDAD_A_COMPARAR THEN
UPDATE `lote_detalle` SET cantidad=cantidad-CANTIDAD_A_COMPARAR WHERE id_lote_detalle = LOTE_DETALLE_IDS;
SET CANTIDAD_A_RESTAR = CANTIDAD_A_RESTAR - CANTIDAD_A_COMPARAR;
ELSE
UPDATE `lote_detalle` SET cantidad=cantidad-CANTIDAD_A_RESTAR WHERE id_lote_detalle = LOTE_DETALLE_IDS;
LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
IF DONE = 1 THEN
LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE cur_id;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Is anything in the cursor?
the query or something?
Is anything in the Syntax?
Cause i have based this Trigger from the syntax of the MySQL Forums
This is the Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur_id CURSOR FOR SELECT id_lote_detalle from lote_detalle WHERE id_inve' at line 9

Comment: where ID_INVENTARIO_IN  does come from?

Comment: comes from a variable:
    DECLARE ID_INVENTARIO_IN INT;
    SET ID_INVENTARIO_IN = (Select id_inventario from detalle_requisicion WHERE id_detalle_requisicion = new.id_detalle_requisicion);

Comment: Also post the exact error message

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur_id CURSOR FOR SELECT id_lote_detalle from lote_detalle WHERE id_inve' at line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least following issues with your code:

1. All declarations should come before any statements (`SET` in your case). **That's what is causing your immediate error.**
2. You didn't declare `DONE` variable
3. You didn't declare `LOTE_DETALLE_IDS` variable, but you declared `ID_LOTE_DETALLE_MIN` which you didn't use. Perhaps you should rename `ID_LOTE_DETALLE_MIN` to `LOTE_DETALLE_IDS` then.
4. Since declarations go first you have to re-write your cursor definition (e.g. with subquery) because `ID_INVENTARIO_IN` variable isn't initialized yet

Your whole declaration section can be re-written in a following manner

```
-- declaration of variables of the same type can be combined
DECLARE ID_INVENTARIO_IN, 
        LOTE_DETALLE_IDS, 
        CANTIDAD_A_COMPARARINT, 
        CANTIDAD_A_RESTAR, 
        DONE INT;
DECLARE cur_id CURSOR FOR ...
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER ...

-- initialize variables
SET ...
```

Now, I believe your trigger most likely can be re-written with just update statement(s). You can get help with it if you explain in plain words what you're trying to achieve and provide exact table schemas and sample data.

Comment: thank yoy, i did what you say and works very well :)